# How does compressor ensure that rfgnt exiting the compressor exits at sufficient pressure such as its condensation tmp is always > otsd air temp?

Tags: thermodynamics, hvac, compressors, refrigeration

I have very basic knowledge of the refrigerant cycle. I am talking about a Split system Home AC with an air cooled condenser. Assume a basic AC reciprocating or scroll compressor (i.e NOT a variable speed type with inverter or VFD).

My understanding is the compressor compresses the low pressure vapor coming out of the evaporator to a higher pressure, to raise the condensation temperature of the refrigerant gas to be above  the outside ambient air temperature.  Essentially A higher discharge pressure raises the condensation point at which the refrigerant will liquefiy. The refrigerant's condensation point  has to be always above 10-15 degrees F above the outside ambient air temperature regardless whether it is 80 F outside or 110 F outside. Then the refrigerant flows to the condenser where it changes phase back to liquid and rejects heat into the surrounding air.

How does the compressor know how much to pressurize the incoming vapor to ensure that the outgoing vapor's condensation temp will always  be above the outside ambient temperature (regardless of whether it is 80 F or 110 F outside)?   Or are compressors designed with a fixed compression ratio based on the assumed maximum outside ambient temperature. Does the compressor always compresses incoming vapor to the same degree/ratio. I am talking about a plain  compressor (i.e NOT a Variable speed, Inverter, VFD). Instead what controls outlet pressure of the compressor is the temperature of the incoming refrigerant from the evaporator (i.e the discharge pressure at the compressor is a dependent variable not a variable that is controlled by the compressor), and the expansion device regulates flow rate.

Comment: Complete an H-S diagram for the cycle and see what is happening.

Comment: the compressor does not care what the outside temp is and is an on-off operation (assume full load).  A range of temps is built in to the design.